# VScode integrated terminal can't compile C source file using custom built GCC

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, terminal

In my WSL2 Debian system, I built an `i686-elf-gcc` toolkit accoding to [GCC Cross-Compiler - OSDev Wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler).
I used VScode's WSL plugin to connect to my WSL2. And then I got error infomation when I try to compile a testing C source file using `i686-elf-gcc` in the VScode's integrated terminal. The terminal use the default `bash` profile, and open a `bash` shell in WSL.
Then I directly open the WSL2 terminal, and use the same command to compile the same source file, and it was compiled well.
Here is the output infos:

```
# Using VScode integrated terminal

colorglass@colorglass:~/source$ i686-elf-gcc -ffreestanding -nostdlib test.c -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=i686-elf-gcc
Target: i686-elf
Configured with: ../configure --target=i686-elf --prefix=/home/colorglass/opt/cross --disable-nls --enable-languages=c --without-headers
Thread model: single
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 13.1.0 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-ffreestanding' '-nostdlib' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro' '-dumpdir' 'a-'
 cc1 -quiet -v -iprefix ../lib/gcc/i686-elf/13.1.0/ test.c -quiet -dumpdir a- -dumpbase test.c -dumpbase-ext .c -mtune=generic -march=pentiumpro -version -ffreestanding -o /tmp/ccBWMHeT.s
i686-elf-gcc: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

# Using Windows terminal
 
colorglass@colorglass:~/source$ i686-elf-gcc -ffreestanding -nostdlib test.c -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=i686-elf-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/colorglass/opt/cross/libexec/gcc/i686-elf/13.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-elf
Configured with: ../configure --target=i686-elf --prefix=/home/colorglass/opt/cross --disable-nls --enable-languages=c --without-headers
Thread model: single
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 13.1.0 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-ffreestanding' '-nostdlib' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro' '-dumpdir' 'a-'
 /home/colorglass/opt/cross/libexec/gcc/i686-elf/13.1.0/cc1 -quiet -v test.c -quiet -dumpdir a- -dumpbase test.c -dumpbase-ext .c -mtune=generic -march=pentiumpro -version -ffreestanding -o /tmp/ccGOa2bV.s
GNU C17 (GCC) version 13.1.0 (i686-elf)
        compiled by GNU C version 10.2.1 20210110, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.0, isl version none
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
......
```

The key differents is

```
cc1 -quiet -v -iprefix ../lib/gcc/i686-elf/13.1.0/ test.c -quiet -dumpdir a- -dumpbase test.c -dumpbase-ext .c -mtune=generic -march=pentiumpro -version -ffreestanding -o /tmp/ccBWMHeT.s
```

```
/home/colorglass/opt/cross/libexec/gcc/i686-elf/13.1.0/cc1 -quiet -v test.c -quiet -dumpdir a- -dumpbase test.c -dumpbase-ext .c -mtune=generic -march=pentiumpro -version -ffreestanding -o /tmp/ccGOa2bV.s
```

It seems the vscode integrated terminal can't using the correct path of `cc1`.
 Are there some ENVs change or reload when using vscode integrated terminal to start a bash shell, How to fix it to use the correct path of `cc1`?

I want to compile C source file in the vscode's integrated terminal using custom built gcc toolkit.